# ER = EPR and Time Travel

Tags: research-level, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, holographic-principle, wormholes

In [Maldacena-Susskind paper arXiv:1306.0533](http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:1306.0533), they propose an idea of

$$\text{ER = EPR}$$

the relation between the wormhole and the quantum entanglement.

which ER means **Einstein Rosen (ER) bridges**, the general-relativity-allowed solutions to the equations of motion that connect far away regions through relatively short wormholes.

EPR means the quantum entanglement, where quantum mechanics gives rise to **Einstein Podolsky Rosen (EPR)** correlations.

> If **ER = EPR**, then what is [Time Travel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_travel) in this relation, **Time Travel = ?**

I am expecting the answer to be some no-go theorem in the quantum entanglement. I have some basic thoughts and ideas, but willing to hear constructive comments.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are asking. Do you mean to ask that if time travel were possible (i.e. the wormhole was traversable) what that would imply on the entanglement side? Then, my first guess would be "Faster than light communication" (i.e. No Time Travel = No Signalling)

Comment: Time travel would be closed-time-like curve in the gravity side (left hand side). What will be the (right hand side) in the equality on the boundary theory by ads/cft.

Comment: see the answer at http://www.physicsoverflow.org/18389