# Does quantum entanglement imply the existence of a non-causal structure connecting space-time together?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spacetime, quantum-entanglement, causality, non-locality

In contrast to a "time-like" or "causal" structure connecting space-time together, Does quantum entanglement imply the existence of a "space-like" or "non-causal" structure holding space-time together as well.

A more general question; is there even any relevance to the *discussion* of the existence of a non-causal structure connecting space-time together?

The reason I ask is because it initially seems too assuming to suggest that causal structure is the only meaningful structure just because it's intuitive; Consider the fact that two space-like separated events are even allowed to exist in a definable space (space-time diagram). Is there nothing physical *in principle* between the two events which can be defined?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "structure holding our universe together" ?  If you're asking about whether quantum entanglement allows for faster-than-light signal propagation, then the answer is no.  I also personally find your last sentence to be confusing.

Comment: @joshphysics *"structure holding our universe together"* I admit was probably not the best choice of words so I modified it.  I know FTL communication of information is impossible however this does not change the fact that there does exist an *effective* relationship between two entangled particles with space-like separation.  In principle this seems strange that the universe would not utilize this property of quantum systems for the sake of some greater mechanism. Consider (as an example) how the universe maintains similar temperatures in places which are separated by vast distances.

Comment: I'm not an expert on cosmology by any means, but I think that inflation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_%28cosmology%29#Motivations explains the homogeneity of the Universe.
Also what you're referring to sounds a bit like Maldacena and Susskind's ER=EPR where they propose a correspondence between non-traversable wormhole and quantum entanglement. Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103350/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A more general question; is there even any relevance to the discussion of the existence of a non-causal structure connecting space-time together?

This part of the question belongs to a future where the quantization of gravity, i.e. space -time, has been definitively established in a theoretical framework without infinities etc.  The term "entanglement" is a shorthand for implying that a specific quantum mechanical solution with specific boundary conditions gives the probability distribution for a specific event.

Space time at present is just the classical space time of general relativity, and in flat space, whatever holds for special relativity with respect to solutions of quantum mechanical boundary value problems should also hold there.

> Is there nothing physical in principle between the two events which can be defined?

This is a special relativity issue.

If the quantum mechanical wavefunction is a solution that gives a probability for a spacelike separation of constituents ofa system, lets say of two particles,  the detection of one will provide information on the quantum state of the other  (though I cannot think of an example off hand, if I do I will edit it in)

Comment: *This part of the question belongs to a future where the quantization of gravity, i.e. space -time, has been definitively established in a theoretical framework without infinities etc. * No, this question has nothing to do with quantum gravity. We don't need a theory of quantum gravity just because a particular situation involves both quantum mechanics and gravity.

Comment: @BenCrowell  I disagree,  one cannot have rigorous mathematical answers with effective theories, thus no basic questions, as are all entanglement questions, can be answered ,imo.

Answer (score -1):

The following contains a simple proof that quantum entanglement does not violate the principle of causality.  http://sweet-haven.com/causality.pdf

Comment: Can you provide something beyond just a link?  Maybe summarize in your own words the contents of the document?

Comment: ZeroTheHero:  Please let me know what your background in this is.  Thanks, Richard Shockley

Comment: You answer will go to the community, not me.